# How to insert new name for column in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

There is a slight problem when I'm creating a new table in phpmyadmin with new field names. I'm using a for loop trying to insert data for the field names. But for some reason I'm getting a error

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '[0] VARCHAR(30)' at line 3".

Here is my code:

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
include ('connection.php');


function getsquad($url, $tablename){

$html = file_get_html($url);

$player = array();

foreach($html->find('td[align=left]') as $element) {
   if ($element->children(0)) { // work only when children exists
          array_push($player ,$element->children(0)->innertext);
   }
}

$length = count($player);

for($i = 0;$i<=$length;$i++){
// Create a MySQL table in the selected database
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE $tablename(

player[$i] VARCHAR(30)")
or die(mysql_error());  
}

echo "Table Created!";

}

$Squad = new squad();
$Squad->getsquad('site', 'Players'); 

?>
```

I know the first part of my function is working so I don't think it is a PHP error but not 100% sure.

Comment: Naming a column `player[n]` isn't possible. What is your goal with this? Creating a separate table per player feels like bad database design, you may want to rethink this approach

Comment: I'm trying to get player names and put it in one table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `$` before player. The right way is:

```
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE $tablename($player[$i] VARCHAR(30)") or die(mysql_error());
```

update:
And as user876345 said, you forget to close the parentheses. So, the code should be:

```
mysql_query(" CREATE TABLE $tablename( $player[$i] VARCHAR(30) ) ") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Worked, Thanks. Small but took time to relise

Comment: Thanks @david-cain for the corrections. I'm new here in the community and I'm learning engligh yet.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed to close the `)` at the end of the query and also missed `$` in `player` variable

```
CREATE TABLE $tablename( $player[$i] VARCHAR(30) )
```

Your code should be like:

```
 mysql_query("CREATE TABLE $tablename($player[$i] VARCHAR(30)") or die(mysql_error());
```